# Speech-to-Text API documentation question

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am taking a look at the Speech-to-Text API and I had some questions:

1. What is the difference between v1 and v1p1?
2. Does the chirp model in Speech-to-Text v2 support transcribing audio from a streaming input?

Comment: Hi, can you specify your question number 1 if it's about the packages or versioning of Speech-to-Text?

Comment: @PoalaAstrid both I guess. When taking a look at the GitHub source codes some examples use ```require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1```  when I refer to the documentation all I can see is that v1p1 is in beta but no explanation of what new features it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versioning denotes different releases or updates to the API, with newer versions often introducing improvements, bug fixes, or new features. This information is generally available in [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/release-notes).

Streaming recognition with the 5 minute limit and transcription of MP3 encoded audio data are available in `v1p1beta1` API version.

The `Chirp model` is not available in Speech-to-Text v2 `Speech.StreamingRecognize` API method.